# Remove rounded corners below UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque on iPhone running iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, statusbar, uistatusbar

Since iOS 6.0 the OS adds rounded corners below the statusbar with style `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` on the iPhone.

Is there a way to remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the statusbar style to `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent` removes the rounded corners. Having a black view behind it, it will look exactly the same like a statusbar with style `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` except of the rounded corners.

You can change the statusbar style using this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Comment: @CalZone When you put a black view behind the transparent status bar, it is indistinguishable from a black status bar